# Unable to normalise json string using json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm attempting to normalise some data using pandas and I can get it to work with a simple example but not with the more complex examples.

I've included my code below and commented which lines do and do not work.

I suspect it may be to do with the not-working json having multiple values for 'DayTypes' whereas the working one does not.

I have tried every permutation under the sun and I have finally accepted defeat and look to your kind souls to please help me.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

json_data = "[{\"DayTypes\":{\"Monday\":\"true\"},\"OpeningHours\":{\"OpenPeriod\"" \
   ":{\"StartTime\":\"07:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"15:00:00.000\"}}},{\"DayTypes\"" \
   ":{\"Tuesday\":\"true\",\"Wednesday\":\"true\",\"Thursday\":\"true\"},\"OpeningHours\"" \
   ":{\"OpenPeriod\":[{\"StartTime\":\"07:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"13:00:00.000\"},{\"" \
   "StartTime\":\"17:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"19:00:00.000\"}]}},{\"DayTypes\":{\"Friday\"" \
   ":\"true\"},\"OpeningHours\":{\"OpenPeriod\":{\"StartTime\":\"07:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"" \
   "20:00:00.000\"}}},{\"DayTypes\":{\"Saturday\":\"true\"},\"OpeningHours\":{\"OpenPeriod\":{\"" \
   "StartTime\":\"08:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"20:00:00.000\"}}},{\"DayTypes\":{\"Sunday\"" \
   ":\"true\"},\"OpeningHours\":{\"OpenPeriod\":{\"StartTime\":\"11:00:00.000\",\"EndTime\":\"" \
   "13:00:00.000\"}}}]"

json_data1 = "[{\"DayTypes\": {\"MondayToFriday\": \"true\"}, \"OpeningHours\": {\"OpenPeriod\": {\"StartTime\": \"06:15:00.000\", \"EndTime\": \"20:40:00.000\"}}}, {\"DayTypes\": {\"Saturday\": \"true\"}, \"OpeningHours\": {\"OpenPeriod\": {\"StartTime\": \"07:10:00.000\", \"EndTime\": \"21:30:00.000\"}}}, {\"DayTypes\": {\"Sunday\": \"true\"}, \"OpeningHours\": {\"Unavailable\": \"true\"}}, {\"DayTypes\": {\"MondayToFriday\": \"true\"}, \"OpeningHours\": {\"OpenPeriod\": {\"StartTime\": \"07:10:00.000\", \"EndTime\": \"13:50:00.000\"}}}]"

# print(type(json_data))

data = json.loads(str(json_data))
data1 = json.loads(str(json_data1))

# this doesn't work :(
# json_normalize(data, 'DayTypes',[['OpeningHours','OpenPeriod','StartTime'],['OpeningHours','OpenPeriod','EndTime']], errors='ignore' )

# this works as expected
json_normalize(data1, 'DayTypes',[['OpeningHours','OpenPeriod','StartTime'],['OpeningHours','OpenPeriod','EndTime']], errors='ignore' )
```

I expect to see a table with the day, starttime and endtime. If there are multiple start and end times for a day then these will simply be new rows in the table.

```
Day             StartTime       EndTime
MondayToFriday  06:15:00.000    20:40:00.000
Saturday        07:10:00.000    21:30:00.000
Sunday          nan             nan
MondayToFriday  07:10:00.000    13:50:00.000
```

UPDATE 1:
If I grab the first item from the list (data[0], 'DayTypes', etc) I get Mondays details. I can also return Fri, Sat & Sun if I call data[2], data[3], and data[4]. If I try data[1] it bombs out. This is 'Tues, Wed, Thurs' as a list.. I'd be happy if these were displayed on a single line.